# Numpy make binary matrix outline continuous and fill it with 1s

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a file containing 0 and 1s here: https://easyupload.io/wvoryj.
How can I fill the shape of these structures with 1s? I think binary_fill_holes is not working because the outline is not continuous.

[plot showing structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8MBy.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage

mask = np.loadtxt('mask.txt', dtype=int)
mask = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(mask).astype(int)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(mask)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Rather than share a download to a file, it would be better to create a minimal example showing what you are trying to do that people can copy from your question.  Please review [ask] and read about how to create a [mcve]

Comment: Your file contains all zeros from my knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be my approach:

- First fill up the gaps with a 2D convolution
- run a cumsum over all rows to fill the outlines
- divide by the last (or highest) number of the row
- set everything larger than 1 back to 1

I hope that helped

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

mask = np.loadtxt('mask.txt', dtype=int)

# run a convolution over the mask to fill out the empty spaces
conv_mat = np.array(3*[[0,1,0]])
mask_continuous = convolve2d(mask, conv_mat)

# add up all numbers from left to right...
# ...and divide by the last value of the row
mask_filled = np.array([np.cumsum(i) / np.cumsum(i)[-1] for i in mask_continuous])

# reset everything larger than 1 to 1
mask_filled[mask_filled>1] = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.imshow(mask_filled)
plt.show()
```